# How to split one Redux reducer into multiple smaller ones

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-reducers

I'm very new to React & Redux and am working on the authentication portion of my app.

The way my backend API works is, once a user signs in, the response contains:

- The JWT token to use for future requests
- An object with the User's data

What I would like to do is have the following occur:

1. Store the token in `localstorage`
2. Set a variable `isAuthenticated` in Redux to `true` (`false` for logout)
3. Store the user information in a second Redux variable called `user`

I've currently the following **Action**:

```
import { SIGN_IN, SIGN_OUT } from "./Types";

export const signIn = response => {
    return {
        type: SIGN_IN,
        payload: response
    };
}

export const signOut = () => {
    return {
        type: SIGN_OUT
    };
}
```

and the following **Reducer**:

```
import { SIGN_IN, SIGN_OUT } from './Types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    isAuthenticated: null,
    user: {}
};

const authReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case SIGN_IN:
            // This logic was removed thanks to comment from Sanish Joseph
            // localStorage.setItem("token", action.payload.token);

            return {...state, isAuthenticated: true, user: action.payload.user};
        case SIGN_OUT:
            // This logic was removed thanks to comment from Sanish Joseph
            // localStorage.removeItem("token");

            return {...state, isAuthenticated: false, user: {}};
        default:
            return state;
    };
};

export default authReducer;
```

and **CombineReducers** code:

```
export default combineReducers({
    ...
    auth: authReducer
});
```

---

This code works, but both `user` and `isAuthenticated` are children of `auth` (in other words, I have to get them both and refer to them via `auth.user` & `auth.isAuthenticated`.

What I don't know how to do is how to write my reducer code so `SIGN_IN` will still send all the data I got from the API, but be able to create *2 separate pieces* of state in Redux `isAuthenticated` & `user`.

Any help would really be appreciated!

Comment: You will have an action where you call your API. You may use Thunk to call your API. There when you get back response you trigger 2 actions. One for the `isAuthenticated` and other for user object. Your local storage logic shouldn't be in the reducer. Move that to your component.

Comment: @SanishJoseph, I completely understand your logic re: the `localstorage` and already updated my code - Thank you so much for that!!! As for the other part re: triggering 2 actions, is that the only / correct way to do it rather than just having one action for `LOG_IN` and a second for 'LOG_OUT` - It seemed more intelligent to me that that should be the only action called and the logic would be split up afterwards. Or am I misunderstanding.

Comment: In your case `isAuthenticated` and `user` are 2 items in your redux store.  You have named part of your store which you want to manage separately as `auth`. In your component when you want to access 1 item you can do it like, `const {isAuthenticated ,user}= useSelector(
    (state: any) => state.auth  );`

Comment: Since both `isAuthenticated ,user` are related what you are doing is correct. If it was a different part of state which is not related to authentication, you can create another reducer and add that in the  `combineReducers` with it's name. So you get 1 store but different pieces of state that can be easily accessed with `useSelector` .

Comment: If you want to move the `user` to a separate part of store and not `auth` then create a new reducer for that and add in the combineReducers.

Comment: Thanks again, @SanishJoseph, I think that last comment of yours is exacly what I'm trying to figure out how to do - What I'm imagining is to call 2 different reducers from within my `authReducer`, so I'd, from my code call `authReducer` with `LOG_IN` and it would, then, split up the work into the 2 separate reducers. Does that make sense / is there any way to do that that is considered good coding practice?

Comment: Nope. Any action can be handled by multiple reducers. So, you trigger an action and your auth reducer will handle the `isAuthenticated` and user reducer will handle the `user` object.

Comment: Every action call goes through all of your reducers. If you are not handling it with your switch cases, it's gonna reach the default and return the portion of the state untouched..

Comment: That idea of 2 separate reducers makes perfect sense!!! - So I just create an `authReducer` and a `userReducer` - THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: If you'd like to post that as an answer, I'll happily accept it.

Comment: I will summarize everything and post as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what I understood from the question is, you want to make isAuthenticated and user as 2 separate parts in the store.

For separating the state into multiple parts, you will need multiple reducers. Another important logic to remember is, all of your reducers will get called when any action is dispatched. It's your decision whether to handle a particular action or not. Multiple reducers can handle same action.

So to create 2 parts one for `auth` and one for `user`, you can create 2 reducers. Remove user handling from auth reducer and add that to user reducer. Action is going to be the same. So in auth reducer,

```
import { SIGN_IN, SIGN_OUT } from './Types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    isAuthenticated: null,
    
};

const authReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case SIGN_IN:           

            return {...state, isAuthenticated: true};
        case SIGN_OUT:          

            return {...state, isAuthenticated: false};
        default:
            return state;
    };
};

export default authReducer;
```

and your user reducer will look like,

```
import { SIGN_IN, SIGN_OUT } from './Types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {    
    user: {}
};

const userReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case SIGN_IN:
            

            return {...state,  user: action.payload.user};
        case SIGN_OUT:
           

            return {...state, user: {}};
        default:
            return state;
    };
};

export default userReducer;
```

and don't forget to combine them,

```
export default combineReducers({
    ...
    auth: authReducer,
    user:userReducer
});
```